# How to enlarge and tint photo with pure CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a feeling this isn't jQuery based, but I'm simply looking for opinions. Notice on mouseover, how the golf players fade out slightly, enlarges the photo size, and gets blurry, and text comes up.  I really want to do that.

http://www.kevinsprecher.com/

It is possible to capture this mouse-over effect with straight jQuery/CSS?

Comment: CSS3 Transforms and Zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect with pure CSS with on :hover. Use jQuery if you need support in older browsers (e.g. IE8).

Check out these resources:

- For the zoom effect: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/
- the image blur: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/
- and if you want to move the image: http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/

Have a closer look at the source of the website you specified as demo:

```
<!-- Source of http://www.kevinsprecher.com/ -->
<div class="c-mb-con" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -610px; display: none; z-index: 4; opacity: 1; width: 610px; height: 325px;">
    <a href="online-golf-lessons.html">
        <div class="ban-ro">
            <h2>Improve You Game With Our Online Golf Lessons.</h2>
            <div class="blog-arrow"><span>+</span>Learn More</div>
        </div>

        <img src="http://imavex.vo.llnwd.net/o18/clients/kevinsprecher/images/Main_Banner/online-golf-lessons.jpg" alt="Improve You Game With Our Online Golf Lessons." title="Improve You Game With Our Online Golf Lessons." width="610" height="325">
    </a>
</div>
```

…and the related CSS Source:

```
#c-mb a img {
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

#c-mb a:hover img, #c-mb a:active img {
    display: block;
    width: 610px;
    height: 325px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Comment: @jeff-noel Hit the submit too early. Answer updated.

Comment: Markus thank you!  This puts me on the right path and gives me something to work with.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann My bad, sir. Here is a small alternative going along the lines of what you posted as an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/xqwDU/

Comment: An example is worth a thousand words.